# Are there electrons in the electron energy levels that are created due to doping in N type semiconductors?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

I was going through [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/solids/dsem.html) article. There it's mention that

> The addition of donor impurities contributes electron energy levels high in the semiconductor band gap so that electrons can be easily excited into the conduction band.

What I don't understand is that how can electron reside in extra electron energy level, when the level itself lie in the bandgap region.

Answer (score 1):

The energy difference between the donor states in the band gap and the bottom of the conduction band is small compared to $kT$. This means a significant number of electrons are excited into the conduction band by thermal interactions i.e. scattering off lattice vibrations.